# Cannot resolve class SearchView

Tags: xml, searchview

So I'm trying to include a search bar in an app of mine when I encountered the error "Cannot resolve class SearchView". Google was unhelpful so I came here. This is my code:

```
<SearchView
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/grid_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The rest of the xml is done correctly, and I got the widget directly from android, so this has confused me. All help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I have resolved the issue, but all input is still welcome for others' benefit.

Comment: please answer your own question if you have resolved it

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you need to specify the complete path of SearchView for android component.

```
<android.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="410dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/grid_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Posting this as an answer as OP did not answer despite resolving the issue.

If your project is using `androidx` you need to use `androidx` components in the layout (which is yet to be a default when placing a `SearchView` item in the design palette).

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/grid_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```